# How do I reset the Core Data stack after restoring sqlite file from backup?

Tags: ios, ipad, core-data

I'm implementing backup/restore functionality for my app, but after I restore the sqlite file from the backup and try to access some data I get this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Object's persistent store is not reachable from this NSManagedObjectContext's coordinator'
```

Back before ARC you could nil out the Core Data objects on the appdelegate, and then they would get rebuilt when you tried to access the ManagedObjectContext.  How do you do it now?

EDIT:

I must be doing something else wrong then.  I can set the managed object context to not be readonly, but I get the same error when I try to access data.  Any advice?

```
- (void)restoreDatabase {

    ICAMAppDelegate *appDelegate = (ICAMAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.managedObjectContext = nil;
    NSError *error;

    // Delete Persistent Store
    NSArray *stores = [[appDelegate persistentStoreCoordinator] persistentStores];
    NSPersistentStore *store = [stores objectAtIndex:0];
    NSURL *storeURL = store.URL;
    [[appDelegate persistentStoreCoordinator] removePersistentStore:store error:&error];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:storeURL.path error:&error];

    NSString * databaseName = @"ICAMMobile.sqlite";
    NSString * databaseBackupName = @"ICAMMobile.sqlite.bak";
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;

    NSString *backupPath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseBackupName];
    NSString *dbPath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

    if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:backupPath])
    {
        if (![fileManager copyItemAtPath:backupPath toPath:dbPath error:&error])
        {
            NSLog(@"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
        else
        {
            [appDelegate.managedObjectContext reset];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's still the same. With the only difference being that nilling the ivars won't leak under ARC.

Comment: I still got the error.  Maybe I'm dong something else wrong.  I added my code above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what worked.
I needed to call `[appDelegate persistentStoreCoordinator] addPersistentStoreWithType` after replacing the file.

**EDIT:**
As a bonus I added my backup database method too.

```
- (void)restoreDatabase {
    ICAMAppDelegate *appDelegate = (ICAMAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSError *error;
    // Delete Persistent Store
    NSArray *stores = [[appDelegate persistentStoreCoordinator] persistentStores];
    NSPersistentStore *store = [stores objectAtIndex:0];
    NSURL *storeURL = store.URL;
    [[appDelegate persistentStoreCoordinator] removePersistentStore:store error:&error];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:storeURL.path error:&error];

    NSString * databaseName = @"ICAMMobile.sqlite";
    NSString * databaseBackupName = @"ICAMMobile.sqlite.bak";
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;

    NSString *backupPath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseBackupName];
    NSString *dbPath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

    if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:backupPath])
    {
        if (![fileManager copyItemAtPath:backupPath toPath:dbPath error:&error])
        {
            NSLog(@"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
        else
        {
            [[appDelegate persistentStoreCoordinator] addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error];
        }
     }
}


- (void)backupDatabase {
    NSString * databaseName = @"ICAMMobile.sqlite";
    NSString * databaseBackupName = @"ICAMMobile.sqlite.bak";
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;

    NSString *backupPath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseBackupName];
    NSString *dbPath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

    NSURL *toURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:backupPath];

    if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:backupPath])
    {
        //get rid of the old copy, only one allowed
        [fileManager removeItemAtPath:backupPath error:&error];
    }

    if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath])
    {
        if ([fileManager copyItemAtPath:dbPath toPath:backupPath error:&error]) {
            [toURL setResourceValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error:&error];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code woks like a charm in xcode4 but when running the code from xcode5 in ios7 it is not working. Can you please help.